# JavaScript RegExp: Different results: Built pattern using string & using regexp "literal"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any differences between using RegExp literals vs strings?

http://jsfiddle.net/yMMrk/

```
String.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(pattern) {
    pattern = pattern + "(?![\s\S]*" + pattern + ")";
    var match = this.match(pattern);
    return (match == null) ? -1 : match.index;
}

function indexOfLastNewline(str) {
    var match = str.match(/\r?\n(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n))/);
    return (match == null) ? -1 : match.index;
}

var str = "Hello 1\nHello 2\nHello 3\nHello4";
alert(str.lastIndexOf("(\r?\n)")); // always returns the 1st newline (7)
alert(indexOfLastNewline(str)); // returns correctly (23)
```

**Update**

even if I use a `RegExp` object, I still get the same result

http://jsfiddle.net/yMMrk/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape your `\` in the string version as `\\`, like this:

```
String.prototype.lastIndexOf = function(pattern) {
    pattern = pattern + "(?![\\s\\S]*" + pattern + ")";
    var match = this.match(pattern);
    return (match == null) ? -1 : match.index;
}

function indexOfLastNewline(str) {
    var match = str.match(/\r?\n(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n))/);
    return (match == null) ? -1 : match.index;
}

var str = "Hello 1\nHello 2\nHello 3\nHello4";
alert(str.lastIndexOf("(\\r?\\n)")); // returns correctly (23)
alert(indexOfLastNewline(str)); // returns correctly (23)
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yMMrk/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you use a string to construct a regex, you need to escape backslashes; if you use a regex literal, you need to escape slashes if they occur in your regex.

So the regex

```
\s/
```

can be written as a JavaScript string like this:

```
"\\s/"
```

and as a JavaScript regex literal like this:

```
/\s\//
```

Also, there is a difference in the handling of mode modifiers. For example, to make a regex case-insensitive, you can construct a regex object from a JavaScript string like this:

```
var myre = new RegExp("[a-z]", "i");
```

With a regex literal, you can do that directly:

```
var myre = /[a-z]/i;
```

Also, see [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).